# How do I change permissions on FAT32 USB drive on Raspberry Pi

Tags: permissions, usb, raspberry-pi4, fat32, plex

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 operating as a Plex media server witgh an externalk USB drive as media storage, the drive mounts and it perfectly usable but after the reinstall of the latest OS I cant remember the setting to allow read write to the USB drive, when I change it in filemanager it fails - any ideas?
Cheers

I've tried lots of different advice from google searches but most seem to be focussed on mounting the drive, its mounted and working perfectly as stroage i just cant delete or add files without plugging the drive into another computer

Comment: In `/etc/fstab` for the device, you probably need need the `user` option - which would allow any user to mount it & make the ownership of all the data by whoever mounted it, or you need some combination of the `uid`, `gid`, `umask`, `dmask` & `fmask` options to ensure either all users, or some subset of users to have either read or read & write control. It is fully explained in the man page for `mount`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but to be honest I need a far more Raspberry pi for dummies answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I am not sure if you want to automatically mount the drive or not so here goes both alternatives.

**1. Mount temporary**

This will mount the drive until the next reboot. Open a terminal and find the path to your drive (if you don't already know)

```
sudo blkid
```

Then to mount it use the following command

```
sudo mount -o umask=0,uid=nobody,gid=nobody /dev/MY_USB_DRIVE /mnt/WHERE_I_WANT_IT_MOUNTED
```

This will mount the drive with read write permissions for everyone.
`uid=nobody` and `gid=nobody` are redundant and just added for clarity.

---

**2. Auto mount at startup**

Open the `fstab` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Then add something like this line to the file

```
/dev/MY_USB_DRIVE /mnt/WHERE_I_WANT_IT_MOUNTED auto users,noatime,umask=0 0 0
```

Also make sure you have created the mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/WHERE_I_WANT_IT_MOUNTED
```

Then change the permission of your mount point using

```
chmod -R 775 /mnt/WHERE_I_WANT_IT_MOUNTED
```

---

Try approach 1 first to make sure it works as intended, then proceed to approach 2 if needed.